# How to get height of individual buttons in a MenuStrip in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, height, menustrip

I have a menu strip, that can have buttons added/removed. I want to be able to get the height of each individual button, and add them up. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this sample code as a guide: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1a7f655b-fd14-4af9-b843-28432d8ce7fb/iterate-through-all-menu-options-in-a-menustrip

The message box gives the Text for each ToolStripItem in MenuStrip1, followed by the height of the ToolStripItem in parenthesis.  The bottom of the message box contains a total of the heights of all the controls in MenuStrip1.

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim total As Integer
    Dim menues As New List(Of ToolStripItem)

    For Each t As ToolStripItem In MenuStrip1.Items
        GetMenues(t, menues)
    Next

    Dim msg As New StringBuilder
    For Each t As ToolStripItem In menues
        msg.Append(t.Text)
        msg.Append(" (")
        msg.Append(t.Height)
        msg.AppendLine(")")

        total += t.Height
    Next
    msg.AppendLine("")
    msg.AppendLine("")
    msg.Append("Total Height: ")
    msg.Append(total)

    MessageBox.Show(msg.ToString)
End Sub

Public Sub GetMenues(ByVal Current As ToolStripItem, ByRef menues As List(Of ToolStripItem))
    menues.Add(Current)
    If TypeOf (Current) Is ToolStripMenuItem Then
        For Each menu As ToolStripItem In DirectCast(Current, ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems
            GetMenues(menu, menues)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```